# non trivial solution for 2 linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have two equations for 'x' and 'y'. equations are as below:

$x \:( s - d) + a x + b \: y = 0 \\
(j \: +1) \: x +  y \: ( s - e) + 9x= 0 $

d,e,,a,j and b are constants I want to find solutions of s for which determinant of the matrix of coefficients of x and y becomes zero (amounts of s, for which  x and y have nontrivial solutions). Could anyone do that? answers with an example will be highly appreciated.

Below is the code I tried:

```
CoefficientArrays[{(- d) x + b y == 0, (j + 1) x + (s - e) y + 9 x == 0}, {x, y}]

mat = Normal[%]

matt = Select[mat, # != {0, 0} &]
Eigenvalues[-matt]
```

Comment: By "linear functions" do you mean $f(x,y)=A+Bx+Cy$? // Without the complete system I can just advise you to use `Solve`.

Comment: have a look at `CoefficientArrays` ( look at the first example under applications)

Comment: Would be better if cut-and-pastable code were provided.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I made the equations easier. which function should I use to find amounts of s which make the determinant equal to zero.  @corey979

Comment: @george2079 but how to find amounts of s which makes the determinant equal to zero?

Comment: Can you at least put your equations in *Mathematica* syntax and include it in your question?

Comment: yes, I will do it.

Comment: I added the code. could you help now? @J.M.

Comment: OK; I guess you need `Eigenvalues[{{d, -b}, {-10 - j, e}}]` then?

Comment: @george2079 could ypu please see the code and tell me wat is the nistake?

Comment: I found the mistake myself  @george2079

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to set the determinant to zero:

```
ca = CoefficientArrays[{
       x (s - d) + a  x + b y == 0, 
       (j + 1) x + (s - e) y + 9 x == 0}, {x, y}]
mat = Normal[ca]
matt = Last@mat
Solve[Det[matt] == 0, s]

(*
{{s -> 1/2 (-a + d + e - Sqrt[a^2 + 40 b - 2 a d + d^2 + 2 a e - 2 d e + e^2 + 4 b j])}, 
{s -> 1/2 (-a + d + e + Sqrt[a^2 + 40 b - 2 a d + d^2 + 2 a e - 2 d e + e^2 + 4 b j])}} 
*)
```