# Simplifying solution of Solve function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I find the solution for the parameter I was searching for, by using  [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133444/non-trivial-solution-for-2-linear-equations).
but the solution is so messy. I want to simplify it and used simplify. But I think there should be a way to simplify it more. The information may be used is:

$k^2 + kk^2 = K^2 $

And the code which I used is:

```
 m = (4 dr - K^2 (d + dd)/2) (k^2 - kk^2) (1 - l ro /2) (d - dd)/4 -v p k l (4 dr - K^2 (d + dd)/2)/4 + v^2 K^2/4 + v k dr l p /4;

dp = (x (v kk/2 (4 dr - K^2 (d + dd)/2) + v kk K^2 (d - dd)/8 + 
    dr l p k kk (d - dd)/4) + 
 y ((xr kk (ro - 1/l) (4 dr - K^2 (d + dd)/2)) + 
    v kk tr K^2 (1/l - ro/2) + dr xr 4 kk (1/l - ro/2)))/m;

a = -v k dp/4 - xr y kk p/2 - l K^2 dp p (d + dd)/8 + (d - dd)/4 k kk x + dr l p dp;

aa = -v kk dp/4 + xr y k p /2 + tr y K^2 (1/l - ro/2) + (d - dd) x kk^2 /4 - K^2 x (d - dd)/8;

ca = CoefficientArrays[{x (s - K^2 (d + dd)/2) + 
  dp (v kk + l (d - dd) k p kk/2) - 
  y (tr ro K^2) - (d - 
     dd) ((kk^2 - k^2) aa + 2 k kk a)/(4 dr - K^2 (d + dd)/2) == 
 0, y (s - dc K^2) + n x == 0}, {x, y}];

mat = Normal[ca];
matt = Last@mat;
Solve[Det[matt] == 0, s]
Simplify[%];
Simplify[%]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried assuming? Like `Assuming[{dr,d,....} \[Element] Reals, Simplify[]]`

Comment: What do ou mean? could you provide an example? @Feyre

Comment: `Assuming[{dr,d,dd,k,kk,l,ro,v,p,y,xr,tr,K} \[Element] Reals, Simplify[%]]`
Note though that `K` is a built in symbol and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: k and kk and K are imaginary. Is there a way to say that they ae imaginary numbers? And also how can I use the information below for more simplifying : \[Alpha] = ro l
TR = tr n / (dc (d + dd)/2)
XR = xr n /(dc (d + dd)/2)
pe = v/(2 Sqrt[ dr (d + dd)/2]) @Feyre

Comment: You could replace imaginary variables with `{k->I k}`, and then assume `k` is Real.
You can add equations to the list of `Assuming`, for instance:
`Assuming[{a == b, b \[Element] Reals}, Simplify[Sqrt[a b]]]` returns `Abs[b]`

Comment: Assuming[{\[Alpha] == ro l , TR == tr n/(dc (d + dd)/2) , 
    XR == xr n/(dc (d + dd)/2) , 
    pe == v/(2 Sqrt[dr (d + dd)/2] , {dr, d, dd, l, k, kk, ke, ro, v, 
         p, y, xr, tr} \[Element] Reals} , Simplify[%]] Is this code ok? @Feyre

Comment: `Assuming[{\[Alpha] == ro l, TR == tr n/(dc (d + dd)/2), 
  XR == xr n/(dc (d + dd)/2), 
  pe == v/(2 Sqrt[dr (d + dd)/2]), {dr, d, dd, l, k, kk, ke, ro, v, p,
     y, xr, tr} \[Element] Reals}, Simplify[%]]`